# Pure Product State Problem Clarification about $\alpha$-closeness and $\beta$-farness

Tags: quantum-algorithms, entanglement, complexity-theory, fidelity

I am reading [a paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.5788.pdf) on entanglement, specifically, determining if a state is close to being entangled or not.

The problem first introduces the $(\alpha, \beta, l)$-Pure product state problem. This problem is defined the following way:

[image: Problem definition]

I am confused though; the only constraint is that $0 < \alpha < \beta \frac{\sqrt{11}}{32} < 2$. But what if the "closeness" (trace norm) of the state is between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ Would the algorithm output Yes or No? And because this is a decision (promise, to be technical) problem, it has to output one or the other. This seems like something obvious that I'm missing, but I don't know.

Comment: I'm definitely not an expert on these things, but they are saying just above that this is a "separability testing *promise* problem". Does that maybe mean that they're studying complexity of this problem under the assumption that one of the two possibilities is realised? The statements won't hold otherwise (well, not with those values of $\alpha,\beta$)

Comment: @glS That could certainly be true. But I don't think its correct because the product-test (the algorithm they use to prove that this problem is in BQP) doesn't have this $\alpha$ and $\beta$ closeness/farness specification. It only requires an error $\epsilon$. Maybe this way introduced for the $1$-LOCC version?